# Iterate over the result of a function in a list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and have got myself confused.

I want to define a function

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
```

it should take a number (e.g. 234) and return the constituent digits (e.g. [2,3,4])

I thought that this...

```
toDigits n = [read c | c <- [show n]]
```

meant

- `show n` i.e. convert 234 to "234"
- use "234" to generate the sequence ["2","3","4"]
- and then apply `read` to each element giving [2,3,4]

but instead I get "234" back out so it must mean

- `show n` i.e. convert 234 to "234"
- use "234" to generate the sequence ["234"]
- and then apply `read` to each element giving [234]

Am I missing a tiny bit of syntax or doing something crazy?

Comment: Small remark: `toDigits :: Integer -> [Int]` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well your idea is really good - let's first give you a working example:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n = [read [c] | c <- show n]
```

now where is the difference? - Well if you do `[show n]`

you produce a list with one string:

```
λ> [show 333]
["333"]
```

and then `read "333"` will just give you back `333` and since it's the only element in the list you get your result

so the obvious solution is to remove the `[..]` from `[show n]` but now you get characters out and `read` wants strings - that's why I re-wrap each character (using `[c]`) before reading

and that is exactly what you wanted (or so I think)